# Python recursive loop woes

Tags: python, recursion

I'm doing some python recursive loop exercises and I have a little problem with one of my routines

```
def buildSentence(timesSay,saySentence):
    if timesSay != 0:
        timesSay -= 1
        if (timesSay % 2 == 0):
            saySentence = "he said that " + saySentence
        else:
            saySentence = "she said that " + saySentence
        return buildSentence(timesSay,saySentence)
    else:
        return (saySentence)


try:
    timesSayInput = int (input("Please enter a number... "))
except ValueError:
    print ("This is not a number!!!")

print (buildSentence(timesSayInput,"she said 'Hello!'"))
```

The code is supposed to output text that alternates with "she said that" and "he said that". When I input 3 (or any odd number), the code works as it should and outputs

```
he said that she said that he said that she said 'Hello!'
```

However, when I enter 2 (or any even number), it outputs

```
he said that she said that she said 'Hello!'
```

Obviously the last "she said that" is repeated, which I do not want to happen. How could I fix this problem?

EDIT: I forgot to mention the text has to end with "she said 'Hello!'"

Comment: Your print one more "she said" in the last print of the code, no matter what the input is

Comment: I know, the problem is that code-generated text always starts with "he said" while I want to change that whether the input is odd or even.

Comment: In that case, end when you hit 1 and not 0, and use the original print statement

Answer (score 0):

**ANALYSIS**

Look at your output: regardless of the input number, you always start with "he said".  You are composing your sentence in the wrong order: you have to *end* with "he said", not lead with it.  That's why half of your results are wrong.

**REPAIR**

Change the order of operations, such that the last phrase you add (when `timesSay == 1`) is *closest* to the sentence, not farthest.  Code is below.

```
def buildSentence(timesSay,saySentence):
    if timesSay > 0:
        if timesSay % 2:
            return "he said that " + buildSentence(timesSay-1, saySentence)
        else:
            return "she said that " + buildSentence(timesSay-1, saySentence)
    else:
        return (saySentence)
```